# Javascript .map function is not returning every thing from an array in Nextjs 13.4 in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Javascript .map function is not returning every thing from an array in Nextjs 13.4 in JSX
In posts.map function only `title`, `content` and `_id` is present. But if i console.log `posts` variable all the data is working and not undefined or not null . It is showing the string store in database but no shown in posts.map() function.

```
const getAllBlogs = async () => {
  await connectDB();
  const blogs = await posts.find({});
  return blogs;
};

async function Blogs(): Promise<JSX.Element> {
  const posts: BlogsProps[] = await getAllBlogs();
  return (
    <>
      <section
        className={`grid max-sm:grid-cols-1 md: grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-6 m-6 cursor-default ${outfit.className}`}
      >
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post._id}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <h1>{post.subTitle}</h1>
            <h1>{post.author}</h1>
            <h1>{post._id}</h1>
            <h1>{post.heading}</h1>
            <h1>{post.quote}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Blogs;
```

Comment: can you show the result from the console.log, just to make sure

Comment: @Ingenious_Hans Sir, If I console.log just before the return JSX all the data is in array of object and now its working if i put JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(posts)) next before the return statement

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return JSX as promise. Use async and await for api request and response in the component.

Try this.

```
const getAllBlogs = async () => {
  await connectDB();
  const blogs = await posts.find({});
  return blogs;
};

function Blogs() {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getBlogs {
      const {data} = await getAllBlogs();
      setPosts(data)
    }

    getBlogs();

  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <section
        className={`grid max-sm:grid-cols-1 md: grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 gap-6 m-6 cursor-default ${outfit.className}`}
      >
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <div key={post._id}>
            <h1>{post.title}</h1>
            <h1>{post.subTitle}</h1>
            <h1>{post.author}</h1>
            <h1>{post._id}</h1>
            <h1>{post.heading}</h1>
            <h1>{post.quote}</h1>
          </div>
        ))}
      </section>
    </>
  );
}

export default Blogs;
```

Comment: This is completely wrong, I am using Server Side Rendering, If i am use useEffect then, i need to switch from server to client component

Comment: @KannuMandora I forgot that it was next.js then use getStaticProps or getServerSideProps instead.